# Eclipse Android Emulator-5554 is always displayed

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, eclipse-kepler

I started to write an android app in Eclipse IDE.
But when I run the app (ctrl+f11), the android device chooser is showing emulator-5554 in state online, even if I did not start any emulator yet.

[image: before my emulator started]

My question is: where does this emulator come from? and for what reason?

My android device chooser when my emulator started:

[image]

Has anyone run into this issue and explains it to me? thanks.

Comment: The 5554 part of the emulator name refers to the port the emulator has taken for connections (e.g. ADB).  If you have more than one emulator running simultaneously, each subsequent will try - and fail - to bind 5554 (the default port) and then try out higher numbers until it gets one.

Comment: Do you use any other android emulator such as BlueStack? Many times such emulator have a service running in background that is shown in AVD.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks to Rohan Kandwal. It is true. While i'm running eclipse, my blue stack is running too and used port 5554. So, this question now closed.

Comment: I too got same issue, but resolved after uninstall of Bluestacks

Answer (score 0):

If you using Bluestack, QUIT (not close) your bluestack program.