# emulator constantly running in the background

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, android-studio

whenever i start eclipse or android studio an emulator is constantly running in the background. when i try to turn it off it restarts again immediately. no matter if i work with a real device or an emulator i have created, this other emulator is not stoppable. in the android debug monitor this emulator is listed as emulator-5554 - Online - ? [2,3,4, debug] (Version API10). i never created or used this emulator, and there is no place to find and delete it.

actually i am able to work with eclipse or android studio with that annoying emulator, but it seems to slow down the performance and i would like to get ride of it.

Comment: What host?  On linux you could use the /proc/pid#/fd directory to figure out what avd it has open and remove that, identify the parent responsible, etc.

Comment: i use windows 7 (64 bit).

Comment: Can you actually find an emulator process running in task manager or whatever windows calls it these days?

Comment: in the task manager i only can find the adb.exe running. if i end it the annoying emulator also ends, but then starts again.

Comment: If you are not finding an emulator process, then likely this is just a "ghost" in the adb devices report due to some minor bug, and not an actual emulator.

Comment: thanks, seems to be realy something like that. i now realized that i can see an emulator-x86.exe in the taskmanager when i start an emulator intentionally, but not when this annoying one runs in the background.

anyway this background emulator also produces constantly logcat messages, like following ones:

2524-2531/system_process E/PGA﹕ PgaSocketWriteAllHdipc: hd_ipc_send() failed
2524-2531/system_process W/PGA﹕ ctlSwapBuffers(133): Host Connect failed, err = -1(0xffffffff)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Were you using BlueStacks back then by any chance? 
It uses the port 5554, and that might have been your problem too!
It happened to me as well and found the solution in another question:

[Eclipse Android Emulator-5554 is always displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21684710/eclipse-android-emulator-5554-is-always-displayed)

Answer (score 1):

Strange, but should be able to kill a "hidden" emulator instance from the command-line by connecting to its console, i.e.:

```
telnet localhost 5554
kill
```

Replace 5554 with your emulator instance's number.

Comment: thanks, but the hidden emulator suddenly disappeared. i don't know what solved the problem because i tried a lot of things without direct effect. so i can not check if your solution would have solved the problem. but if it happens again i will check it out.

Comment: cannot connect to that emulator via telnet

Answer (score 0):

I use AndroVM. For me its perfect.

Todo is:

- install [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) first
- download [AnroVM](http://androvm.org/blog/)
- file will open in VirtualBox
- start the machine and set USB debug on (settings >> dev. options)
- in commandprompt goto your "sdk\platform-tools" type adb connect 192.168.15.101

When it's ok you will see your device in Eclipse.

edit: When your Eclipse is not working well, just download a new bundle again

Comment: This is not an answer to the question asked

Comment: I saw it when I was given the answer. Sorry